# Does MsBuild SonarQube Runner support encryption?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I see on the page [Settings Encryption](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Settings+Encryption) a section about the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner configuration file.
But the documented portion has a format which doesn't match the example SonarQube.Analysis.xml file.

However, I have tried putting these properties in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml file, in a format corresponding to the [current one](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/master/SonarQube.Bootstrapper/SonarQube.Analysis.xml). Long story made short, the msbuild.sonarqube.runner puts the {aes}encrypted password in the Basic authorization field of the HttpRequest sent to SonarQube.

I guess that the client should unencrypt the password before putting it in the Authentication header. Otherwise, the sonarQube server won't allow the user to query the properties Uri (something like /api/properties?resource=projectKey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, I've fixed the documentation to reflect the effective format of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.

Regarding the encryption of the `sonar.password` property, this is currently not supported by the MSBuild Scanner: It does not (yet?) know about the encryption logic, and therefore sees the raw encrypted value only. However, some other properties can be encrypted: the ones that are read during the `end` step of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, which is under the hood launching the sonar-runner.

I've created the following ticket to keep track of this limitation: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-192